# "Wear off" or "ware off"

Tags: idioms, orthography

Iv'e seen both spellings of the phrase. Is one correct and the other incorrect or are they both acceptable? Does one belong to British English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Ware off" is simply incorrect regardless of whether we're talking British or American English. It is not in use at all.

See: http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=wear+off%2C+ware+off&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: That's what I thought, but after I saw it appear once on a website I searched it on google and it came up with over 150,00 hits! Check for yourself - lots of people are spelling it like that.

Comment: @Mark A couple of million Google hits for "Currently online now", which is redundant in most of the cases: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/41251/10341

Comment: internet - a faster and more powerful way for the blind to lead the blind. in other words, yes, 150,000 people CAN be wrong!

Answer (score 0):

I have always used the assimilation factor of the proper use of this phrase:
   If anything were to be "worn off"? Then in relation to its friend, would be to "wear off." So....I'd go with "wear off".   d*